# Center a text on one column

Tags: tabularx

How can I center only 'coluna 3'? I tried to create a new column type without success.

[image]

Thank you

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{D}{>{\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\small
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
    >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}D
    >{\hsize=1.4\hsize}D
    >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}D
  }

\toprule
\textbf{Coluna 1} & \textbf{Coluna 2} & \textbf{coluna 3}\\
\midrule

\multirow{4}{=}{Neque porro quisquam} & Quisque eget augue ac diam egestas facilisis a non sapien. Phasellus nec feugiat ligula & 1 \\
 & Ipsum & 2 \\
 & Dolor & 3 \\
 & Consectetur & 4 \\
\hline

\multirow{3}{=}{Ut aliquam lacus id malesuada sagittis} & Pellentesque & 5 \\
 & Adipiscing & 6 \\
 & Amet & 7 \\

\bottomrule

\end{tabularx}
\caption{Ut aliquam lacus id malesuada sagittis}
\label{tab:locaiseduracao}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: what if you  replace `\centering`  with `c` ?

Comment: Hi, it keeps the output without error. https://imgur.com/a/UHHa7G3 however I notice that what I want it a little diferent. I'll update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\centering` should be in the `>{...}` and, as it's in the last column, use `\arraybackslash` to restore the tabular meaning of `\\`

so not

```
>{\hsize=0.8\hsize}\centering
```

but instead

```
>{\hsize=0.8\hsize \centering\arraybackslash}
```

Comment: note as you show in your image using X column for the third column is forcing the table to be wide and harder to read, I would use a `c` column for the third column so it is natural width

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a problem with the last version of `array`.  A work-around: replace the tabularx preamble with

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
    >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}D
    >{\hsize=1.4\hsize}D
    >{ \hsize=0.8\hsize\hfill}D<{\hfill\null}
  }
......
```

[image]